# Using BeautifulSoup to Parse Table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to use BeautifulSoup to extract the data from an HTML Table and transform it into a n x 7 data frame with columns: Date, Transaction, Manifest Number, Date Shipped, Payment Type, Amount, and Prepaid Balance.

Snippet of my code so far:

```
def find_account_status(htmls):
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
table = soup.find('table', border="0", cellpadding="2")
table2 = table.find_all("td", {"class": "bodytext"}, text=True)
print(table2.text.split())
```

Here is a snippet of the HTML I'm trying to extract: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html):

```
import pandas as pd

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmls)
table = soup.find('table', border="0", cellpadding="2")
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
```

Comment: Tried downloading lxml from Pycharm but I get the following error: ERROR: b"'xslt-config' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"

Comment: Because when I run your code, I get the error "lxml not found, please install it"

Comment: @RileyHun well, there is plenty of information about problems and solutions to installing lxml, just google them. Or, you may change the parser by providing the `flavor` argument ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)).